# Corrupted ActionBar look

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I've noticed this issue a long time ago but only now i was able to prepare demo which clearly reproduces it. The issue is presend on 2.1 emulator and on my ICS 4.0.3 device.

In application i have AsyncTask which may adjust visibility of actionbar indeterminate progress and reinit menu by calling invalidateOptionsMenu . This should hide refresh icon. This is working ok until i modify listView data model and call notifyDataSetChanged on adapter. After such action Actionbar may have broken view.

Expected view:
[image]

Broken view (Last item disappears forever or blank space added insted of in some cases):
[image]
[image]

The causing code is in onPostExecute

```java
    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                adapter.items.add(i);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            activity.stopLoading();
        }
...
    void stopLoading()
    {
        if (loaders.decrementAndGet() == 0)
        {
            setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }
```

Any idea why is this happening and in most cases because of updating listview adapter (or perhaps some over view updates)? If i remove line adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); actionbar will not be broken in the demo. But in real application it may be broken because of another reason also (can't determine exactly all the issue causes)

Project demonstrating an issue: http://goo.gl/ZbMTU

Opened ActionBarSherlock issue: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/887

UPD:
Keep digging on this issue. Seems that not exactly adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() causes invalid look, but the requestLayout call by the AdapterView.AdapterDataSetObserver which is listening for the data set changed event in the ListView

The workaround exists, i can call invalidateOptionsMenu and setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility in the handler.post. But it forces to use even custom implementation of FragmentPagerAdapter which calls fragment.setHasOptionsMenu in the delayed handler.post

What i want is to find the most efficient way to invalidate view and actionbar without corrupting it.

Comment: You should call supportIvalidateOptionsMenu() not InvalidateOptionsMenu()

Comment: It is not the real cause, such as i can't control it everywhere. For example in Fragment.setMenuVisible

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you did this in doInBackground:

> Thread.sleep(randomSleep);

But, in the class "LoadingTask", comment the lines in the "doInBackground" that the problem will be solved.

see:

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
//          int randomSleep = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
//          try
//          {
//              Thread.sleep(randomSleep);
//          } catch (InterruptedException e)
//          {
//              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//              e.printStackTrace();
//          }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: that doInBackground is for simulation of real work. Usually it can be some network related operation which takes some time.